# Memory being filled up in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, optimization

I am running this code :

```
for (i <- Range(1, listOfCities.value.length)) {
      val city = listOfCities.value(i)
      logger.info(s"Started with city=$city")
      val data = getDataFromQueries(redshiftConnector, sparkSession, city)
      val transactions = data.map { pidData =>
        pidData.p_list.trim.split(',')
      }

      val result: RDD[CRule[String]] =
        run(sparkSession, transactions.rdd, numPartitions)
      val resultWithCity = result.map { rule =>
        (rule, city)
      }
      val df: DataFrame =
        convertResultToDataframe(sparkSession, resultWithCity)
      writeToRedshift(redshiftConnector, df, tableName)
    }
```

Each result consists of lacs of rows. The code works fine for 2-3 cities. But then the memory of the workers begins to fill up and the program becomes painfully slow. Why is the memory being filled up? Is garbage collection not happening or is there some memory leak in my code? I am monitoring the memory requirements for each city and it just doubles everytime without falling when a city completes. 
How should I clean up the RAM after each iteration? Thanks

Configuration - 3 m4.2xlarge workers, 8 nodes, 30 GB RAM, 6 executors with 4 cores each

Answer (score 1):

It is a pretty bad practise to use a for loop in Spark because the Spark optimizer is basically to dumb for it.

My idea would be to first get all the data into one common dataframe. So basically you  would do the following:

```
    var city = listOfCities.value(1)
    var data = getDataFromQueries(redshiftConnector, sparkSession, city)
    for (i <- Range(2, listOfCities.value.length)){
    var city = listOfCities.value(i)
    var data = data.unionAll(getDataFromQueries(redshiftConnector, sparkSession, city))
    }
```

Afterwards just continue with your programm for the "big" dataframe